# Get and save value from Dataservice Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, dataservice

I'm trying to learn Flex, I setup a simple Air application with PHP server as dataserice...

In my php class there is a function `counttotal` that return a simple `int` value.

```
  <s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   xmlns:demologicaclass="services.demologicaclass.*"
                   width="682" height="397" showStatusBar="false" initialize="init()">
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        protected var count:int = 0;
        protected function init():void
         {
            counttotalResult.token = logicaservice.counttotal();
                    count = counttotalResult.lastResult as int;
         }
         protected function get_count():void
         {              

                 Alert.show(count as String);
         }
  .....
  .....
<s:Label id="countitems" left="10" bottom="39" width="221" height="21" 
                 fontSize="20"
         fontWeight="bold" text="{counttotalResult.lastResult as String}"/>
    <s:Button right="10" bottom="39" label="Controlla" click="get_count();"/>
```

In the label I got the correct value, but I can't save and show the value into/from a simple variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because using the keyword **as** will make Flex to try to cast a type to another, with a risk that the cast fails. Here, you try to cast a String as an integer, which basically means you do the following :

> take 'blabla' and check if it's an integer. If it is, put its value in
>   count, otherwise put null in it.

What you want to do is transtype (not sure about the word, though) a String to an integer. To do this, use the following syntax :

```
count = int(Number(counttotalResult.lastResult));
```

The above means

> Take lastResult, and convert it into a Number, and then into an int.

The conversion can fail (but it wont, as long as lastResult is the string representation of a valid number), and the syntax could be shorter, but in a nutshell, that's the difference between casting a type to another, and converting a type to another.

Comment: parseInt(str) OR parseFloat(str) should be used.

Comment: Well, then, sorry for my wrong answer, I would have been stuck the same way ! And thanks for the tip, M.D. !